# Vector initialization using a bracket after the name of the vector

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

I'm currently interested in c++ Program. However, while I was looking into my friend's works, I noticed a strange vector initialization

```
vector <int> dist(1+n, INF);
```

Is it completely the same as

```
vector<int> dist[INF];
```

Comment: The first snippet creates vector of size `1+n`, the second creates array of `INF` different empty vectors.

Comment: [A `vector` Construction reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) might help you.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen The first vector will have the size is `1 + n` elements, all elements initialized to the value `INF`.

Comment: The first one is a normal vector initialization.  The second one is a strange array of vectors.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, sorry. I can never remember which parameter comes first.

Answer (score 1):

The first snippet `vector <int> dist(1+n, INF);` initializes a vector of size 1+n containing INF integer each, for instance if we initialize a vector **vec**

```
vector<int> vec(3, 5);
```

this creates a vector vec of size 3 having a value of 5 for each of its elements, **vec[0] = vec[1] = vec[2] = 5**

nd for the second snippet `vector<int> dist[INF];`, this creates INF number of empty vectors so if we have `vector<int> dist[5]`, this creates 5 empty vectors v[0],v[1]...v[5] (where v[0],v[1]...v[5] are all empty vectors). We can then use any vector methods on these empty vectors like v[0].push_back(5).